# displaying sequence of images in Java

Tags: java, video

I am trying to execute a MPEG Decoder in Java. This decoder produces a series of Bitmap Images as per the frame rate of the video. I want it to be displayed in a window. I am absolutely new to this, and I don't have any idea about how to get started.

Can anyone please tell me what are the options and how should I get started?

Thanks !

Comment: Look at this, for example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javampeg1video/

Comment: *"I am absolutely new to this, and I don't have any idea about how to get started."* Start with [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).  And consider starting with simpler projects.

Comment: well, I know basics of Java language and program in it comfortable. However, I have never experimented with GUI as such.

Comment: You could start here: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/java2dtutorial/java2dimages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325546/how-to-color-a-pixel), which helped me get started.

Thanks !