# Buffered image inside a GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I was thinking about making a GUI with a text input field, and on the right have a bufferedImage, which updates on the input i enter in the "console". Is it possible to have these two in the same GUI?

What I was thinking about was this example:
[image]

I've made a code where I only have a bufferedImage, but I want to add the left part of the image above, and I'm a bit stuck on how?

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Math;

// From SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325804/12989146
public class DirectDrawDemo extends JPanel {

    final private BufferedImage canvas;
    final private Color def_c = Color.BLACK; final private Color def_bg = Color.WHITE;

    public DirectDrawDemo(int width, int height) {
        canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        fillCanvas(def_bg);
        drawCircle(def_c,300,300,100);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(canvas, null, null);
    }


    public void fillCanvas(Color c) {
        int color = c.getRGB();
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y++) {
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawCircle(Color c, int x_center, int y_center, int r){
        // inspiration : https://www.gatevidyalay.com/mid-point-circle-drawing-algorithm/
        int x=r, y=0, p = 1-r;

        // checking for radius of circle
        if(r==0){
            drawPoint(x_center,y_center,c);
        }
        if(r<0)
            return;

        // initialising point p
        while(x>y){
            y++;
            if (p < 0) {
                p = p + 2 * y + 1;
            } else {
                x--;
                p = p+2*y-2*x+1;
            }
            //print all octaves
            drawPoint(x + x_center,y + y_center,c);     // 1. (x,y)
            drawPoint(y + x_center,x + y_center,c);     // 1. (y,x)
            drawPoint(y + x_center,-x + y_center,c);    // 4. (y,-x)
            drawPoint(x + x_center,-y + y_center,c);    // 4. (x,-y)
            drawPoint(-x + x_center,-y + y_center,c);   // 3. (-x,-y)
            drawPoint(-y + x_center,-x + y_center,c);   // 3. (-y,-x)
            drawPoint(-y + x_center,x + y_center,c);    // 2. (-y,x)
            drawPoint(-x + x_center,y + y_center,c);    // 2. (-x,y)
        }
        //show
        repaint();
    }
    void drawPoint(int x,int y,Color c){
        canvas.setRGB(x,y, c.getRGB());
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 940;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Direct draw demo");

        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        DirectDrawDemo panel2 = new DirectDrawDemo(width, height);
        //panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        //JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        //label1.setText("Enter x");
        //JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();

        frame.add(panel2);
        //panel.add(label1);
        //panel.add(textField1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

So I've tried what was told in the comments and it seems that i have the idea on how to place the different BorderLayouts as I want, but i have one issue now..
When I run my program The window is totaly BLANK (just white), but when I resize the window just a little or something everything pops up?

Here is my new code I've made:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GUI extends JPanel {
    final private BufferedImage canvas;
    final private Color def_c = Color.BLACK; final private Color def_bg = Color.WHITE;


    public static void main(String[] args){

        int width = 1280; int height = 720;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        /*----- Sub panels -----*/
        GUI panel_Canvas = new GUI(width, height);

        //Add sub panels to this CENTER layout
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Adding to panel 2
        panel2.add(panel_Canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

    public GUI(int width, int height) {
        canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        fillCanvas(def_bg);
        int x0 = 0;
        int x1 = 500;
        int y0 = 0;
        int y1 = 300;
        //drawRect(Color.RED, 0, 0, width/2, height/2);
        drawLine(def_c, x0, y0, x1, y1);
        //drawLineRecInit(Color.yellow, x0, y0+2, x1, y1+2);
        drawCircle(def_c,300,300,100);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(canvas, null, null);
    }


    public void fillCanvas(Color c) {
        int color = c.getRGB();
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y++) {
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }


    // Implementation from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#All_cases
    public void drawLine(Color c, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
    {
        int dx = Math.abs(x1-x0);
        int sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
        int dy = -Math.abs(y1-y0);
        int sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;
        int err = dx + dy;  /* error value e_xy */
        while (true)   /* loop */
        {
            canvas.setRGB(x0, y0, c.getRGB());
            if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1) break;
            int e2 = 2*err;
            if (e2 >= dy) /* e_xy+e_x > 0 */
            {
                err += dy;
                x0 += sx;
            }
            if (e2 <= dx) /* e_xy+e_y < 0 */
            {
                err += dx;
                y0 += sy;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawLineRec(Color c, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int dx, int dy, int err)
    {
        canvas.setRGB(x0, y0, c.getRGB());
        if(!(x0 == x1 && y0 == y1))
        {
            if((2*err) >= dy)
            {
                if((2*err) <= dx)
                {
                    drawLineRec(c, x0 + (x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1), y0 + (y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1), x1, y1, dx, dy, err + dx + dy);
                }
                else
                {
                    drawLineRec(c, x0 + (x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1), y0, x1, y1, dx, dy, err + dy);
                }
            }
            else if((2*err) <= dx)
            {
                drawLineRec(c, x0, y0 + (y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1), x1, y1, dx, dy, err + dx);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawCircle(Color c, int x_center, int y_center, int r){
        // inspiration : https://www.gatevidyalay.com/mid-point-circle-drawing-algorithm/
        int x=r, y=0, p = 1-r;

        // checking for radius of circle
        if(r==0){
            drawPoint(x_center,y_center,c);
        }
        if(r<0)
            return;

        // initialising point p
        while(x>y){
            y++;
            if (p < 0) {
                p = p + 2 * y + 1;
            } else {
                x--;
                p = p+2*y-2*x+1;
            }
            //print all octaves
            drawPoint(x + x_center,y + y_center,c);     // 1. (x,y)
            drawPoint(y + x_center,x + y_center,c);     // 1. (y,x)
            drawPoint(y + x_center,-x + y_center,c);    // 4. (y,-x)
            drawPoint(x + x_center,-y + y_center,c);    // 4. (x,-y)
            drawPoint(-x + x_center,-y + y_center,c);   // 3. (-x,-y)
            drawPoint(-y + x_center,-x + y_center,c);   // 3. (-y,-x)
            drawPoint(-y + x_center,x + y_center,c);    // 2. (-y,x)
            drawPoint(-x + x_center,y + y_center,c);    // 2. (-x,y)
        }
        //show
        repaint();
    }
    void drawPoint(int x,int y,Color c){
        canvas.setRGB(x,y, c.getRGB());
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I added a button

[image]

Then I added the action listener in the GUI main
[image]

On a button click this is called, but doesn't update the view?

[image]

the java view
[image]

This is DrawCanvas
[image]

Comment: That's what layout managers like [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) are used for. You can place the input field and the buttons in a separate `JPanel` and add it to the left of your `DirectDrawPanel` by adding it into the `frame` with `frame.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);`

Comment: Okay i will try that thanks :)

Comment: @ThomasKläger Hello again Thomas I've tried what you said, and updated the post in the EDIT section, but now I run into an issue where the page starts totally white (blank). But when I resize the window everything pops up? can't find the issue here

Comment: Never mind I moved the `frame.setVisible(true);` to the last line in the code, and how it works

Comment: @ThomasKläger maybe you know, but I've made a input-textfield where the user can type and I retrive the text as a string, lets say I type "1", and make a if statement to check for this specific "1", and inside the if I call a new `drawCircle(...)` how do I update my `BufferImage` with this new circle? because when I do it now and run the function nothing new is displayed? :) 
I maybe have to do an update or something, but thought my `repaint();` did that..

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is. To test I've added a button that draws an additional circle, and clicking on that button leads to an updated image that shows up. Are you sure that `drawCircle()` is called?

Comment: @ThomasKläger It looks like the drawCircle is run, but nothing is shown, only if i hardcode a value before i add it to the frame. If you want to take a look at the project, to test type `1` into the textfield. I've postet it here, just type `we.` tl/t-lfIHLYwf8E

Comment: Sorry it's not the full project, only the files, just saw that.. hope you are still able to run/look at it

Comment: @ThomasKläger how did you even make it work with a button?

Comment: when i do the following `testButon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DrawCanvas p = new DrawCanvas();
                p.drawCircle(300, 200, 100);
            }
        });` nothing happends, the repaint() is called inside drawCircle()

Comment: Ïf you create a `new DrawCanvas()` then you have to add it to the frame. I added `testButton.addActionListener(e -> panel_Canvas.drawCircle(Color.BLUE, 250, 250, 200));` to the `GUI.main()` method after the `GUI panel_Canvas = new GUI(width, height);` line.

Comment: @ThomasKläger cant make it work still, sorry for that, I'm glad that you are trying, I've posted my pictures of what you told me, maybe you can spot what i do wrong?

Comment: @ThomasKläger if it helps, could you try to post you example? I have my project here: `wetransfer.com/downloads/f5d4281c5ec108bd9edb815ad27a217820210304212025/f96ce2` then you could reupload it, and i could look at how to? because I'm a bit lost, I've been sitting with the issue for too many hours haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame will only redraw its child components. The `ActionListener` of your `testbutton` however creates its on `drawCanvas` that is never added to the frame and is therefore never included in the frames redraw.

Instead of that you will need one `DrawCanvas` that you add to the frame and that you do your redrawing on.

I've used the `GUI` class from your question and replaced the `main()` method with the following two methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(GUI::createFrame);
}

private static void createFrame() {
    int width = 1280; int height = 720;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
    panel3.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    /*----- Sub panels -----*/
    GUI panel_Canvas = new GUI(width, height);

    //Add sub panels to this CENTER layout
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Adding to panel 2
    panel2.add(panel_Canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // *** These 3 lines below added *** //
    JButton b = new JButton("Circle");
    panel1.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(e -> panel_Canvas.drawCircle(Color.BLUE, 250, 250, 200));

    frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

I've added just three lines to create a `JButton` with an `ActionListener` that draws an additional circle.

Or, with your updated code: replace the main method with this fragment:

```
static JButton testbutton = new JButton();
static DrawCanvas drawCanvas = new DrawCanvas();
static TextDemo = new TextDemo();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        createAndShowGUI();
        testbutton.addActionListener(e -> drawCanvas.drawCircle(250, 250, 200));
    });
}
```

and replace part where you place the panels on the frame with

```
frame.add(testbutton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(textDemo, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.add(drawCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH;
```

Comment: Many thanks! made it work with a textArea also! :D so now i can call multiple drawings at once!

Answer (score 1):

I created the following GUI as a basis for what you want to accomplish.

[image: Drawing Demo GUI]

The two valid commands are "line" and "circle".  The application generates random endpoints for a line and a random center point and radius for a circle.

So, here are the important points that I want you to take from the code I'm going to post.

1. Always start your Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that your Swing components will be created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. Create an application model using plain Java getter / setter classes.  I used this model to keep all the commands typed, so I could reproduce the drawing.
3. Use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  I used a `GridBagLayout` to create the control panel on the left.  The `GridBagLayout` is not the easiest layout to learn, but it's one of the most flexible.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could paste this code as one block.   Generally, you put separate classes in separate files.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawingDemoGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawingDemoGUI());
    }
    
    private DrawingModel drawingModel;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private JTextArea textArea;
    
    private JTextField inputField;
    
    public DrawingDemoGUI() {
        this.drawingModel = new DrawingModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(drawingModel);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        
        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        inputField = new JTextField(20);
        inputField.requestFocus();
        panel.add(inputField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new SubmitListener());
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private DrawingModel drawingModel;
        
        public DrawingPanel(DrawingModel drawingModel) {
            this.drawingModel = drawingModel;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (Command command : drawingModel.getCommands()) {
                if (command.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {
                    Point a = command.getOrigin();
                    Point b = command.getDestination();
                    g2d.drawLine(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
                } else if (command.getCommand()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
                    Point a = command.getOrigin();
                    int radius = command.getRadius();
                    int diameter = radius + radius;
                    g2d.drawOval(a.x - radius, a.y - radius, 
                            diameter, diameter);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class SubmitListener implements ActionListener {

        private boolean firstTimeSwitch = true;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String command = inputField.getText().trim();
            
            if (!firstTimeSwitch) {
                textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            
            textArea.append(command);
            inputField.setText("");
            drawingModel.addCommand(command);
            repaint();
            
            firstTimeSwitch = false;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class DrawingModel {
        
        private List<Command> commands;
        
        private Random random;
        
        public DrawingModel() {
            this.commands = new ArrayList<>();
            this.random = new Random();
        }
        
        /**
         * We;re going to hard code a couple of commands. 
         * This is where you would define
         * your drawing commands.
         * 
         * @param command
         */
        public void addCommand(String commandString) {
            if (commandString.equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {
                Command command = new Command();
                command.setCommand(commandString);
                command.setOrigin(createRandomPoint(10, 380));
                command.setDestination(createRandomPoint(10, 380));
                commands.add(command);
            } else if (commandString.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
                Command command = new Command();
                command.setCommand(commandString);
                command.setOrigin(createRandomPoint(50, 200));
                command.setRadius(random.nextInt(40));
                commands.add(command);
            }
        }
        
        private Point createRandomPoint(int offset, int range) {
            int x = random.nextInt(range) + offset;
            int y = random.nextInt(range) + offset;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }

        public List<Command> getCommands() {
            return commands;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Command {
        
        private int radius;
        
        private Point origin;
        private Point destination;
        
        private String command;

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public Point getOrigin() {
            return origin;
        }

        public void setOrigin(Point origin) {
            this.origin = origin;
        }

        public Point getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }

        public void setDestination(Point destination) {
            this.destination = destination;
        }

        public String getCommand() {
            return command;
        }

        public void setCommand(String command) {
            this.command = command;
        }
        
    }

}
```